# textbox.Focus() not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, focus

am wondering why this code fails to focus the textbox...?

```
private void sendEmail_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    String sendTo = recipientEmail_tbx.Text.Trim();
    if (!IsValidEmailAddress(sendTo))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter valid Email address","Cognex" MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
        recipientEmail_tbx.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile—the best overload match for the `MessageBox.Show` call has some invalid arguments. Once that's fixed (I specified a caption), the code works exactly as expected and sets the focus to the textbox. What's the problem? Do you want the text that has already been entered to appear *selected*?

Comment: @Cody:its edited...check now:)

Comment: Like I said, even once I fixed the call to `MessageBox.Show` by adding a caption string (exactly the same thing you did), the code still works fine. After the message box is displayed, the focus is set back to the textbox. Why do you say it's "not working"? Were you hoping for the text that has been entered in the textbox to appear selected/highlighted?

Comment: no no...if cursor stops in text box thats enough...but its not working here..even I tried this.ActiveControl=recipientEmail_tbx...no luck :(

Comment: @Sisya: Did you tried Select() instead?

Comment: @Daniel:yup...even its not working for me..horrible!!

Comment: @Sisya: mmm it seems to be other issue. Maybe when you are focusing the control, the form is not selected, or blocked by a background operation?

Comment: how can form is not selected ?send button is in the same form

Comment: I've tried several different things (like a default button on the form) to see if I can't throw a wrench into the operation, but I still can't repro the situation you describe. Can you give us any more information about your setup?

Comment: Have you tried checking your recipientEmail_tbx's TabStop if it is set to `true`

Comment: @all:thanks for ur time...I fixed it by using this.Focus..:) MessageBox pop up was the culprit here..

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use `Select()` instead:

```
recipientEmail_tbx.Select();
```

> Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors. Instead, application programmers should use the **Select** method or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or the Activate method for forms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx

Comment: `Error 1 No overload for method 'Select' takes 0 arguments `

Comment: The parameterless overload has existed since 1.1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.select.aspx

Comment: When Select() does not work for you: Often some other control takes the focus. So ensure that your call to Select() to your control is the last one.

Comment: This did it for me. TextBox control inside a GroupBox was not getting focused with .Focus().  inputTextBox.Select() worked!

Answer (score 12):

Add Delay some `miliSec`. Delay then call `Focus()` and Not forget to put inside `Dispatcher`.

```
Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(_ =>
     {
         Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
         {
             TextBoxNAme.Focus();
         }));
     });
```

Comment: While I don't like these hacky "add-a-delay-to-make-things-work" type of solutions, it did get me out of a bind on my multi-threaded C# app. So thanks and +1 for you good sir!

Comment: Works great, thank you man

Answer (score 3):

Even I tried with lots of above solutions but none of them worked for me as am trying to focus on page load. Finally I got this solution and it worked.

```
private void txtBox_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBox.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Use Select() instead!

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Form_Activated** event handler, in conjunction with a `firstActivation` boolean.

```
private bool firstActivation = true;
private Control firstWindowsControl = null;

...

private void DynamicForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (firstActivation)
    {
        firstActivation = false;
        bool fwcPresent = (firstWindowsControl != null);
        Console.WriteLine($"DynamicForm_Activated: firstWindowControl present: {fwcPresent}");
        if (fwcPresent)
        {
            firstWindowsControl.Focus();
        }

    }
```