# Sending a LeftClick event to a Text Box

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Is there any way I can send a left click event to a `TextBox`?  for what ever the reason although I am doing a `TextBox.Focus()` and the cursor is blinking inside the `TextBox` but I cannot start typing in it, But if I do an extra click with the mouse inside the text box then I can start typing. So, I was wondering how to send that event to it?

Comment: As posted [here][1], use .select() instead


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594194/textbox-focus-not-working-in-c-sharp

Comment: As posted [here][1], use .`select()` instead


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594194/textbox-focus-not-working-in-c-sharp

Comment: I have tried SElect, that didn't work either.

Comment: @ValentijnSpruyt: When typing a comment click "help", you will see how to do links ;-)

Comment: Sorry about that, not the best StackOverflow poster appearantly :D

Comment: Fix the activation problem instead of putting a band-aid on it.

Comment: @HansPassant :) Ok I added a this.Activate on the form_Shown Event handler, hofully that fixes it. It is just reproducible on Citrix, so been waiting for it go go through build on its citrix box .

Comment: @BDotA - I remember having that problem with a Citrix app a few years ago.  I don't remember if we fixed it, but the fact that it's Citrix based is a very significant part of the issue.  If this doesn't fix it, you should probably edit or re-ask based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send mouse events, you'll need to import `user32.dll` and use `mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);`

**Example**

```
class Mouse
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02; //Left click
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08; //Right click
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

    public static void sendMouseRightclick(Point p)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, p.X, p.Y, 0, 0); //Sends a mouse right click at the specified Point
    }
    public static void sendMouseClick(Point p)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, p.X, p.Y, 0, 0); //Sends a mouse left click at the specified Point
    }
}
```

When using this, you may call `Mouse.sendMouseClick(Point p)` to send a mouse left click at the specified point.

In your case, I think that you might want to use `Mouse.sendMouseClick(TextBox.Location);` to send a mouse left click at the current `TextBox` position.

Thanks,

Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok to fix this first we should make sure the form itsself is activate.
To do that, in the Form_Shown event we should call this.Activate()