# What is wrong with the following leave event?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub txtAddress_Leave (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
        System.EventArgs) Handles txtAddress.Leave
  If Len (txtAddress.Text) >= 0 Then
         MsgBox ("Need to enter address", MsgBoxStyle.OKOnly, _
         txtAddress.Focus()
  End if
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your *problem* here?

Comment: What do you mean? What's the issue you are having?

Comment: I don't think anything's wrong with it. It's a nice event, and you can see by its behavior that it was raised in an environment full of care and love. Or is it not giving you the results you expect, and in that case, what would you like it to do that it isn't doing?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to check if the user entered text, then you should change this

```
if Len (txtAddress.Text) >= 0 Then
```

to

```
if Len (txtAddress.Text) = 0 Then
```

However, you should better use .NET methods:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text) Then ' or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace
```

You should also use `Select` instead of `Focus`.

```
txtAddress.Select()
```

[textbox.Focus() not working in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594194/textbox-focus-not-working-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The OP has the Focus part happening in the MsgBox call, too.

Comment: @LarsTech: What do you mean? I have mentioned the `Focus` issue.

Comment: Look at the underscore the line above the Focus line.  The OP is missing a closing parenthesis and the title of the MsgBox becomes "True" or "False" because the Focus() is being passed a parameter to MsgBox.  Should be a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Len(txtAddress.Text) >= 0 Then
```

should be

```
If txtAddress.Text.Trim = "" Then
```

That way it takes into account if someone decides to just enter "spaces" as an address. Right now your code will cause the message box to popup if they actually did enter something.