# .Focus() doesn't work in TextChangedEvent

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, textchanged

I have implemented some code in my Windows Form C# program, and the problem is that I want to have the following code in `TextChangeEvent` instead of the `Validating` event, but the `.Focus()` and `.Select()` methods don't work.

What is the solution for this?

```
private void jTextBox5_TextChangeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (jTextBox5.TextValue != "John")
    {
        jTextBox5.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `.Select()` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594194/textbox-focus-not-working-in-c-sharp))

Comment: @Joelius i tried that too, still doesn't work

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you mean by *"[the] methods don't work"*, specifically what behavior are you trying to enforce here? Typically if the `Text` of a control is changing, then it already has `Focus`, so it's pointless to try to give the control `Focus` at that moment.

Comment: Also, what kind of control is `jTextBox5`? The winforms `TextBox` control does not have a `TextValue` property.

Comment: @RufusL i want to be able to only edit that textbox unless the text in the textbox is "john",in other words, the .focus() doesn't function as it supposed to be in the TextChangeEvent and it lets me edit other textbox regardless of the if condition writen in it

Comment: @RufusL i have Jcontrols thats why its TextValue instead of Text.

Comment: Ok, but you're in the `TextChanged` event. The control already has focus when that event is fired. When the focus changes, the `TextChanged` event does not get fired. I believe there's a `Leave` and/ or `LostFocus` event you can use if you want to validate when they try to select another control.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
private void jTextBox5_TextChangeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (jTextBox5.Text.ToUpper().Trim() != "JOHN")
    {
        ((Textbox)sender).Focus();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I could not be of help then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to enforce that the user can only type the word "John" into the textbox, and you want to validate this on each key press, then you can do something like the following code, which examines the current text, one character at a time, and compares each character to it's counterpart in the word "John".

If a character doesn't match, then we set the text to only the substring of characters that *do* match, so they can continue typing:

```
private void jTextBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var requiredText = "John";

    // Don't allow user to type (or paste) extra characters after correct word
    if (jTextBox5.Text.StartsWith(requiredText))
    {
        jTextBox5.Text = requiredText;
    }
    else
    {
        // Compare each character to our text, and trim the text to only the correct entries
        for (var i = 0; i < jTextBox5.TextLength; i++)
        {
            if (jTextBox5.Text[i] != requiredText[i])
            {
                jTextBox5.Text = jTextBox5.Text.Substring(0, i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the selection to the end of the text so they can keep typing
    jTextBox5.SelectionStart = jTextBox5.TextLength;
}
```